# Generate/populate a id like a000001,a000002 without using ID INT IDENTITY sql server

Tags: sql

How can i generate  a000001,a000002 in a loop? (int+1)
varchar(6) or char(6)
without using INT IDENTITY 
help thanks

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter as INT 
DECLARE @MaxBranchId as INT
DECLARE @id INT 
DECLARE @val as varchar(6)      
SELECT  @MaxBranchId= count(*) 
FROM branch
Set @LoopCounter =0
Set @id=1
WHILE(@MaxBranchId is not null and @LoopCounter < @MaxBranchId)
BEGIN


update Branch set branchId= @val
SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1    
END
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop?  That is the wrong way to solve this problem.

Comment: I want to populate a00001,a00002 ... to a existing table with value currently it is null. using a loop will be easier

Comment: If you are simply generating incremental numbers why not use an identity and forget the "a" prefix. And as @GordonLinoff already stated. A loop is completely the wrong way to do this. This should be a single update statement, likely using ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: you could also use an identify field and store your prefix in another column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a partial answer, you may get some idea based on the query.

Using this query you can create a row number and generate a auto increment id.

```
SELECT 'a' + REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(BranchId)) + CAST(BranchId AS VARCHAR) AS NewBrachId , BranchId
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) BranchId FROM Branch ) A
```

Based on that value you can join with the actual branch table and update as per your requirement.

Sample execution with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Branch (
    BranchId VARCHAR(7) NULL,
    BranchName VARCHAR (500)
);

INSERT INTO Branch (BranchName) VALUES
('Branch 001'), ('Branch 002'), ('Branch 003'), ('Branch 004'), ('Branch 005'), 
('Branch 006'), ('Branch 007'), ('Branch 008'), ('Branch 009'), ('Branch 010');

CREATE TABLE #Tmp_TableForBranchUpdate (BranchName VARCHAR (500), BranchId INT);

INSERT INTO #Tmp_TableForBranchUpdate (BranchName, BranchId) 
SELECT BranchName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) BranchId
FROM Branch

UPDATE BR SET BranchId = TE.NewBrachId
FROM Branch BR
JOIN #Tmp_TableForBranchUpdate UT ON UT.BranchName = BR.BranchName 
JOIN (
    SELECT 'a' + REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(BranchId)) + CAST(BranchId AS VARCHAR) AS NewBrachId , BranchId
    FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) BranchId FROM Branch ) A 
    ) TE ON TE.BranchId = UT.BranchId

DROP TABLE #Tmp_TableForBranchUpdate

-- SELECT * FROM Branch
```

Comment: Thanks  you so much, Arulkumar

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sequence in sql server

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testseq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1

SELECT
    concat('a', RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(varchar(5), NEXT VALUE FOR testseq), 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a CTE and `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select b.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from branch b
     )
update toupdate
    set branchid = 'a' + right('000000' + cast(seqnum as varchar(255)), 6);
```

There is no need for a looping construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 1 AS ANCHOR 
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ANCHOR +1 FROM CTE A
)
SELECT TOP 100 CONCAT('a',RIGHT(CONCAT('00000',ANCHOR),6)) AS RecurrenceValue FROM CTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Good to give some code, but it should come with some explanation to point the changes and why it is the solution of the OP's question.